# How can I sort an object array in C# based on user input?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array that is populated with user input and needs to be sorted according to a particular property. I have looked at similar questions on here but it does not seem to help my specific situation and so far nothing I've tried has worked.

The properties for the array are defined in a separate class.

It's a basic program for loading employees onto a system and the output needs to be sorted according to their salary.
*Note that I am a student and I am possibly missing something very basic.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Instantiating_Objects
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(); // Instantiantion

            // Object Array
            Cleaner[] clean = new Cleaner[3]; // Empty Object Array

            Cleaner[] loadedCleaners = LoadCleaners(clean);

            
            for (int i = 0; i < loadedCleaners.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine(loadedCleaners[i].Display() + "\n Salary: R" + loadedCleaners[i].CalcSalary());
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        

        public static Cleaner[] LoadCleaners(Cleaner[] cleaner)
        {
           
            for (int i = 0; i < cleaner.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your staff number");
                long id = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter your last name");
                string lname = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter your first name");
                string fname = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter your contact number");
                int contact = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter your number of hours worked");
                int hours = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("");


                // Populating object array
                cleaner[i] = new Cleaner(id, fname, lname, contact, hours);

            }

            Array.Sort(, )

            return cleaner;
        }
    }
}




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Instantiating_Objects
{
    class Cleaner
    {
        private long staffNo;
        private string lastName;
        private string fName;
        private int contact;
        private int noHours;
        private double rate = 380.00;

        public Cleaner() { }

        public Cleaner(long staffId, string name, string surname, int number, int hours)
        {
            this.contact = number;
            this.fName = surname;
            this.lastName = name;
            this.staffNo = staffId;
            this.noHours = hours;
        }

        public int GetHours() { return noHours;}
        public long GetStaffID() { return staffNo; }
        public string GetSurname() { return lastName; }
        public string GetName() { return fName; }
        public int GetNumber() { return contact; }

        // Calculate Salary

        public double CalcSalary()
        {
            double salary = 0;

            if(GetHours() > 0 &&  GetHours() <= 50)
            {
                salary = GetHours() * rate;
            }
            else if (GetHours() > 50)
            {
                salary = (GetHours() * rate) + 5000;
            }

            return salary;
        }

        public string Display()
        {
            return "\n Staff no: " + GetStaffID() + "\n Surname" + GetSurname()
                + "\n Name: " + GetName() + "\n Contact no: " + GetNumber();

            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Linq... Linq is always the answer :) `return cleaner.OrderBy(x => x.CalcSalary()).ToArray()`

Comment: If you wish to use `Array.Sort` then you want to use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_Sort__1___0___System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___0__) which allows you to pass an `IComparer` that determines which property to sort by,

Comment: Note that your Cleaner class has no properties - those are just private fields with related methods to return each value.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Really cleared things up nicely and it makes a lot more sense now, being cleaner and way more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will combine Legacy code and Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp into one.

First thing as Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp said your Cleaner class has no properties.
I removed all your methods and changed it with properties instead

```
    public class Cleaner
    {
        public Cleaner(long staffId, string name, string surname, int number, int hours)
        {
            StaffNo = staffId;
            FName = name;
            LastName = surname;
            Contact = number;
            NoHours = hours;
        }
    
        public long StaffNo { get; set; }
    
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    
        public string FName { get; set; }
    
        public int Contact { get; set; }
    
        public int NoHours { get; set; }
    
        public double Rate => 380.00;
    
        public double Salary
        {
            get
            {
                double salary = 0;
    
                if (NoHours > 0 && NoHours <= 50)
                {
                    salary = NoHours * Rate;
                }
                else if (NoHours > 50)
                {
                    salary = (NoHours * Rate) + 5000;
                }
    
                return salary;
            }
        }
    
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "\n Staff no: " + StaffNo + "\n Surname" + LastName
                + "\n Name: " + FName + "\n Contact no: " + Contact;
        }
    }
```

Now that we have fixed the class we can look at the `Program Main method`.
Because we changed the cleaner class to use properties instead we can easily use Linq to orderby

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(); // Instantiantion

    // Object Array
    var clean = new Cleaner[3]; // Empty Object Array
    var loadedCleaners = LoadCleaners(clean).OrderBy(_ => _.Salary).ToArray();

    foreach (Cleaner v in loadedCleaners)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine(v + "\n Salary: R" + v.Salary);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

You will notice that on this line

```
var loadedCleaners = LoadCleaners(clean).OrderBy(_ => _.Salary).ToArray();
```

that i am using Linq to order the Salary.
For more on Linq check out the following docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/

**On a side note**
I would say consistency is key, this will keep your code clean.
Look at the following example, the naming convention is inconsistent

```
public Cleaner(long staffId, string name, string surname, int number, int hours)
{
    StaffNo = staffId;
    FName = name;
    LastName = surname;
    Contact = number;
    NoHours = hours;
}
```

Nice, clean and easy to follow

```
public Cleaner(long staffId, string firstName, string lastName, int number, int hours)
{
    StaffId = staffId;
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
    Number = number;
    Hours = hours;
}
```

Comment: This makes way more sense and makes it much easier to manage. Also eliminated entire blocks of unnecessary code. Thanks.

Comment: Mark as answered if its what you wanted